# integration of slideshow with light box

Tags: mootools

i am using mootools for the slideshow in these i wanna add lightbox on click of slideshow image 
my slideshow code is following. so plz tell me how i integrate lightBox with it.

getAll($sql);*/

?>



    noobSlide - mootools
    
    
    
    
    

    
    window.addEvent('domready',function(){
        //SAMPLE 1 (auto, every 5 sec)

        //SAMPLE 3 (play, stop, playback)
        var nS3 = new noobSlide({
            box: $('box3'),
            items: [],
            interval: 3000,
            startItem: 4,
            autoPlay: true,

        });

        //SAMPLE 4 (walk to item)


    });
    








    
        
             $value)
            {

            ?>
            business_photo_thumb_path_web.$value['sPhotoName'];?>" alt="Photo" width="215" height="160"/>

```
    </div>
</div>
<p class="buttons">
    <span id="playback3">&lt; Playback</span>
    <span id="stop3">Stop</span>

    <span id="play3">Play &gt;</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example [LightBox Example](http://www.digitalia.be/demo/slimbox/)

[Lightbox 2 site example](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#example)